# Pure Excel: How do I reference a column wit a dynamic number?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I create a random number in my excel sheet (using RAND), 5 for example. Now I want to reference column A[my number], in this example its A5. How would I do that?

If thats not possible, is it possible to get a random row value from a column?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but the 5 is calculated, its not static, you know? I dont know what the number will be when I write my formula.

Comment: See my answer below - I replied before you edited)

Comment: This is actually a useful question, if not strictly related to programming.  Is there another stack exchange site we should move it to?

Answer (score 2):

`=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;10))` will randomly return cell in range `A1:A10`.

Comment: How would I do that when I reference another sheet in the same file, for example column a in sheet data? Normally I would say data!A5.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("data!A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;10))`

Answer (score 2):

Usually INDEX is preferable to INDIRECT (it's not volatile and you don't need to "hardcode" the column reference). If you have your random number in B3 try

`=INDEX(Data!A:A,B3)`